# Google Sheets Api как настроить и связать с таблицей?

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Всем доброго дня!
Выполняю задачу, по которой необходимо создать Гугл таблицу и через Гугл АПИ получить из неё данные, занося их в БД, добавляя еще одну колонку. На начальном этапе уже встрял. Не могу нормально настроить апишку.
В общем, задание такое:
Необходимо разработать скрипт на языке Python 3,

который будет выполнять следующие функции:

1. Получать данные с документа при помощи Google API, сделанного в [Google Sheets](необходимо копировать в свой Google аккаунт и выдать самому себе права).
2. Данные должны добавляться в БД, в том же виде, что и в файле –источнике, с добавлением колонки «стоимость в руб.»

   a. Необходимо создать DB самостоятельно, СУБД на основе PostgreSQL.

   b. Данные для перевода $ в рубли необходимо получать по курсу [ЦБ РФ]
3. Скрипт работает постоянно для обеспечения обновления данных в онлайн режиме (необходимо учитывать, что строки в Google Sheets таблицу могут удаляться, добавляться и изменяться).

Подскажите, уважаемые знатоки, с какой стороны подобраться? Как вникнуть?

Итак, дополняю.
По итогам шаринья по гуглу получилось настроить апишку и связать с Sheets. Теперь не могу разобраться, как парсить эту таблицу, ведь из неё необходимо достать данные и внести их в БД.

Код, чтоб затестить, видит ли питон данные в таблице, такой:

```
import gspread

path_to_keys = gspread.service_account(
    filename='D:\Programs\pythonProject\Test for the Chanelservice\resources\keys.json')

test_sheet = path_to_keys.open('14DJ3GP4oPVDyJgpg0PhWXA61qp_Cc67qX5QmRfB2t8c')

print(test_sheet.sheet1.get('A1'))
```

Вот только вывод дает ошибки. Что не так?
Может кто-то посоветует, какой библиотекой воспользоваться для решения этой задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Итак, всё решилось таким вот кодом:

```
path_to_keys = gspread.service_account(
    filename='D:/Programs/pythonProject/Test for the Chanelservice/resources/keys.json')

test_sheet = path_to_keys.open('Test for the Chanelservice')
```

немного изменил то, что было написано выше и всё заработало.